# Excel: Count not empty cells ignoring duplicates with same id

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have a table with an "id" column and a "data" column.

[image]

I want to count all not empty cells (or "X") in the data column, but each "x" must be counted only once within the same id block.
The ids are always ordered in blocks (so no 1,2,1 but always 1,1,2,2, etc.) but not necessarily sorted by height (so 12,12,2,2, etc. is also possible).

The result in the example is 2. If another "x" would be added withing the id 2 block, the count would increase to 3. If all Xes would be set the result would still be 3.

I solved this with a VBA script but I was wondering whether this could be achived with an excel formula (some sort of matrix formula I guess).

I use Office 365.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be "cleaner" ways, but this will work:

```
=SUM(N(COUNTIFS(A1:A11,UNIQUE(A1:A11),B1:B11,"x")>0))
```

[image]

Comment: `=SUM(N(` is an alternative shorter start to the rest of your formula.

Comment: You are right, no need for sumproduct. Is there any difference between -- and N besides length?

Comment: Not in this regard, just length =)

Comment: Just wonderfull! Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

[image]

Formula in `A9`:

```
=IFERROR(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[id],Table1[data]="x"))),)
```

**Note:** `IFERROR()` is there just to output 0 when no 'x' is found.